# Will the UK tax my American 401k if I roll it over?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom

I now live in the UK.  I am here on a Tier 2 intracompany transfer visa.  I have a 401k from my last job which I haven't yet rolled over.  I'm pretty sure the UK won't tax me on that if I roll it over ..... right?  Does anyone have any links?

Comment: If your company supported your transfer visa, they might also be prepared to help you with the cost of professional advice on this sort of question (I know my company do, for example).

Answer (score 1):

The UK taxes uk income only. As long as the rollover takes place outside of the UK, you should be fine.

The reverse would have been the problem- Americans are taxed on income regardless of where it comes from. If you had rolled over the equivalent of a "British 401k" ( I realize there is no such thing, but hopefully you get the idea ) in the uk, as an American citizen, you would have been liable for American tax, only subject to the foreign earned income exclusion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I haven't been able to find this documented anywhere on the .gov.uk websites.